# Jackson serialization of interface with multiple subtypes

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this JSON format which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "actionA": {
    ....
  },
  "actionB": {
    ....
  },
  "actionC": {
    ....
  }
}
```

However, only one of `actionA`, `actionB` and `actionC` may appear in the JSON at the same time.

I would like create a Java representation of this which I can serialize to JSON using Jackson. These are the classes I've created so far.

```
public record Content(String name, Action action) {
...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ActionA.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ActionB.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ActionC.class)
})
public interface Action {
...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("actionA")
public record ActionA(...) {
...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("actionB")
public record ActionB(...) {
...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("actionC")
public record ActionC(...) {
...
}
```

This almost does what I want, however this creates an additional level in my JSON called `action`, so a serialized object might look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "action": {
    "actionA": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I've googled this quite a bit but I haven't been able to find a solution. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: are properties on action a,b and c the same?

Comment: @NgoTuoc No, they are distinct from each other. However they fulfill similar roles in the JSON so logically it makes sense to represent them as implementations of the same interface in Java.

Comment: I think it's the Map<String, Interface>  action a,b,c that implements those interface

Answer (score 1):

The additional level `action` is created because you have declared the `@JsonTypeInfo` to work as a **wrapper object** in the line `include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT`. Instead of using `WRAPPER_OBJECT` you can try other options from the enum below and select what is suitable.

```java
public static enum As {
        PROPERTY,
        WRAPPER_OBJECT,
        WRAPPER_ARRAY,
        EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
        EXISTING_PROPERTY;
}
```

You can refer this [java doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html) for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I've tried the different options you listed and they all end up with the additional action level.

Comment: Have you tried `PROPERTY` option? This gives me the output like this. `{"name":"foo","action":{"type":"actionA",...}}`. It does not contain two levels as action and actionA like your output. Instead it keeps the name `actionA` as a property (I have named the property as `type`). However the your action record named as `action` since you have declared it's name in the definition of the record `public record Content(String name, Action action)`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. But having the action level with a type property inside it is not what I want to achieve. I want the action object to change it's property name based on the type of the Java object.